# loopback parent model - how to set properties and create child models

Tags: node.js, model, loopbackjs, extend, strongloop

I have several loopback models and I want to add shared functions to them.
I'm not really sure if I understand loopback's `extend` approach, but I created a `Dictionary` model, set other models `base` property to Dictionary and got stuck here.

Essentially I need to create an instance of child model, fetch some data and build a hash. Then I plan to call app.models.ChildModel.createHash() several times in the boot script to create dictionary for each of the models.

I'm not sure where to start.. how do I pass the child class name (or instance) to parent? I obviously need it to query the data.

I made a working solution for a concrete `Regions` model

```
module.exports = function(Regions){
var countriesHash={};
Regions.setup=function(next){
    Regions.find({where:{type:'Country'}}, function(err, countries){
        countries.forEach(function(country){
            countriesHash[country.id]=country;
        });
        console.log('hash built');
        next();
    });
};
```

but I want to refactor it to abstract `Dictionary` class and just set a few properties like child name and `where` in concrete models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mixin` ([here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+mixins)) to put shared functionalities there and use in models.

Also you can send them some options.

Comment: I tried using mixin 
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
    Model.createHash=function(next){
        Model.find({where:options.where}, function(err, items){
but items are empty, I think that's because of generic Model, not a specific model instance.

Comment: strike that, it's working perfectly. I guess last time I tried the mixin there was some other error which emptied the result. all good now, thanks a lot.